# Loading real terrain into three.js using free map data

Tags: three.js, terrain, satellite-image

Has anyone got any ideas on how to load real terrain data into a three.js scene.

I would like to have a 3D model on a the actual terrain , i.e the elevations and overlayed satellite imagery .

Create scene : ok
Load and animate models : ok
Terrain and satellite imagery : ???

Thanks in advance.
Jon

Comment: I have found a solution that answer your question. The answer i have posted has no code; but is correct. Did you found the solution you were searching? Don't forget to check an approved answer; or answer your own question so the question will be considered closed.

Answer (score 3):

Three.js [has an example on how to make a terrain](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain), so that one's covered.
Regarding the satellite imagery, you'll use that as a texture on your terrain. The only thing that is important is to get the texture coordinates right, so that may end up being tricky.

[This blog post](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/textural-terrains-with-threejs.html) gives a good example and its code is available online, too.

Comment: From further investigation , the appear to be various types of terrain data , where the general trend is to have a X Y Z and ideally an added RGB colour ( for HD Camera Laser scanners ) . So I am going to try to focus on CSV files ( due to their simplicity ).http://papaparse.com/ will be used to stream the points into the three.js scene , and the point will be cooured by the RGB .  Ideally the use of the octree function should be used to reduce memory usage , as the point cloud scans are very large . I have tried to use http://potree.org/wp/ however the .las format is not as robust as the csv

Answer (score 3):

If you some how have, or able to calculate, the elevation data of the points needed in grid mode.

- You can use plane geometry and [javascript xml Loader](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp) to load your data to the [planes' geometry vertices](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PlaneGeometry).
- Use any type of material for the plane you need and define the "map" attribute to add the image texture loaded with  [ImageLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/ImageLoader)

  If you have random placed elevation data you can use [face3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Face3) or other type of three.js geometry and an algorithm to create a TIN (triangulated irregular network) to visualize the terrain.

Also you might want to take a look at [cesium library](https://cesiumjs.org) and [cesium.js documentation](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/index.html) as about the geospatial part of the question, about the terrain loading using [this three.js method](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs.html) and  [this osg.js demo](http://server.pointcloudviz.com:9090/).